# RestKit 0.20.0-rc1 - How do I map multiple error parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, restkit

I'm currently using the RKErrorMessage class to map an error message from my server like so:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"message" toKeyPath:@"errorMessage"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *errorResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping
                                                                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                                                                keyPath:@"error"
                                                                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];
```

But now I would like to map an additional parameter from my server, for instance the error title (or anything else for that matter). My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "error":{
        "title":"This is the error title"
        "message":"This is the error message",
    }
}
```

The idea is that I can directly map some of these error messages to UIAlertViews if something ever goes wrong when my app is accessing the server. This can be done already with *only* the error message but adding a title seems to make it fit well with UIAlertView.

From looking at the RKErrorMessage class I see that it only has two parameters: errorMessage and userInfo. How would I go about doing this?

**UPDATE:** The reason I'm trying to do this with RKErrorMessage is that it automatically maps to the NSError passed into the failure block in the RestKit get/post/put/etc methods... which is pretty nice.

```
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/somethingsomething/" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Comment: I know this is not what you're asking for... but in my experience you should try to stay away from RestKit.

Comment: This has become my experience as well. Unfortunately, I didn't know that going in so I am stuck, for the meantime, with RestKit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do what you originally asked (not sure why you accepted the answer that didn't actually answer your question):

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"userInfo"]];
RKResponseDescriptor *errorResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:errorMapping
                                                                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                                                                keyPath:@"error"
                                                                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassClientError)];
```

The key difference from your sample code is this line:

```
[errorMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"userInfo"]];
```

Then, from the failure block callback, you can access the userInfo dictionary like:

```
NSString *message = [[[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey] objectAtIndex:0] userInfo] objectForKey:@"message"];
NSString *title = [[[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey] objectAtIndex:0] userInfo] objectForKey:@"title"];
```

RestKit will automatically map all attributes of the JSON's "error" dictionary to the RKErrorMessage's userInfo dictionary.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did there. Good thinking. I will give this a try the next time I have a chance (though that may not be soon).

Comment: Ya I had to do the exact same thing you intended to do, and I accomplished it with this.  Good luck.

Comment: Adding a property mapping with `toKeyPath:@"userInfo"` does not work, when using the `RKErrorMessage` class.  I had to use the target key path as "errorMessage".

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `RKErrorMessage` ???

> The RKErrorMessage is a simple class used for representing error
>   messages returned by a remote backend system with which the client
>   application is communicating.

I think the best way is to create the custom object to map your paramteres.

```
@interface MyCustomErrorObject : NSObject

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *message;

@end
```

Comment: This was always plan B. I was trying to avoid this because the RKErrorMessage to NSError mapping is convenient. See update.

Comment: @docksteaderluke can you elaborate on what this solution actually was. were you able to continue using getObjectsAtPath? I'm running into the same thing. I went down a MyCustomErrorObject-esque path, but I still don't see how to get at that object once in the failure block.

Comment: 1. Map the error like so:
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyCustomErrorObject class]];
2. Add the response descriptor.
3. In the failure block get the error object here:
[error.userInfo objectForKey:RKObjectMapperErrorObjectsKey]